# Simple Roll-Down With Spark Dataframe (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

If you have a simple dataframe that looks like this:

```
val n = sc.parallelize(List[String](
    "Alice", null, null, 
    "Bob", null, null,
    "Chuck"
    )).toDF("name")
```

Which looks like this:

```
//+-----+
//| name|
//+-----+
//|Alice|
//| null|
//| null|
//|  Bob|
//| null|
//| null|
//|Chuck|
//+-----+
```

How can I use dataframe roll-down functions to get:

```
//+-----+
//| name|
//+-----+
//|Alice|
//|Alice|
//|Alice|
//|  Bob|
//|  Bob|
//|  Bob|
//|Chuck|
//+-----+
```

Note: Please state any needed imports, I suspect these include:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{WindowSpec, Window}
```

Note: Some sites I tried to mimic are:

http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html

and

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

I've come across something like this in the past so I realize that Spark versions will differ. I am using 1.5.2 in the cluster (where this solution is more useful) and 2.0 in local emulation. I prefer a 1.5.2 compatible solution.

Also, I'd like to get away from writing SQL directly - avoid using `sqlContext.sql(...)`

Comment: Do you have a column to allow the positioning of the null values? With the example you gave, the order cannot be deterministic because DataFrames are distributed, so the null values will be at different places each time you run your code. If you have another column that allows you to define some ordering (or grouping), than the solution is not very hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another column that allows grouping of the values, here's a suggestion:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (Some("Alice"), 1),
  (None, 1), 
  (None, 1), 
  (Some("Bob"), 2), 
  (None, 2), 
  (None, 2), 
  (Some("Chuck"), 3)
).toDF("name", "group")

val result = df.withColumn("new_col", min(col("name")).over(Window.partitionBy("group")))

result.show()

+-----+-----+-------+
| name|group|new_col|
+-----+-----+-------+
|Alice|    1|  Alice|
| null|    1|  Alice|
| null|    1|  Alice|
|  Bob|    2|    Bob|
| null|    2|    Bob|
| null|    2|    Bob|
|Chuck|    3|  Chuck|
+-----+-----+-------+
```

On the other hand, if you only have a column that allows ordering, but not grouping, the solution is a little harder. My first idea is to create a subset and then do a join:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (Some("Alice"), 1),
  (None, 2), 
  (None, 3), 
  (Some("Bob"), 4), 
  (None, 5), 
  (None, 6), 
  (Some("Chuck"), 7)
).toDF("name", "order")

val subset = df
  .select("name", "order")
  .where(col("name").isNotNull)
  .withColumn("next", lead("order", 1).over(Window.orderBy("order")))

val partial = df.as("a")
  .join(subset.as("b"), col("a.order") >= col("b.order") && (col("a.order") < subset("next")), "left")
val result = partial.select(coalesce(col("a.name"), col("b.name")).as("name"), col("a.order"))

result.show()

+-----+-----+
| name|order|
+-----+-----+
|Alice|    1|
|Alice|    2|
|Alice|    3|
|  Bob|    4|
|  Bob|    5|
|  Bob|    6|
|Chuck|    7|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Unfortunately, the data is wider than I provided in the example and there isn't any grouping which makes the first choice less desireable. It looks like the second option can be done easily by adding a monotonically incrementing counter (as a column), but the second is a still a much more complex solution than I would expect with Spark and Scala. I am holding out a while to see if there are other simpler solutions

Comment: @codeaperature I agree the second solution is not simple, and maybe there is a better one, but I can say that usually Spark is not optimal when the problem includes neighbouring dependency or conventional iterative logic, so maybe there is not a simple solution for your problem.

Comment: SIDEBAR: There is a small bug in this when the last item (name) is null or None.